# Coletar os dados de um JTable e enviar para um List

Tags: java, jtable, lista

Na minha aplicação Java, tenho uma tela de venda onde os produtos que são selecionados vão para um `JTable`. Ao finalizar a venda, preciso coletar os dados da `JTable` e entregar para o método de impressão, que fica em outra classe. Só que não estou conseguindo imaginar a forma mais correta de criar o `List` e entregar ao outro método.

Abaixo vou colocar o código por onde estou caminhando.

**TelaVenda.java**

```
public void capturaProduto(){
    ArrayList lp = new ArrayList();

     for (int i = 0; i < TbProdutosVenda.getRowCount(); i++) {
         lp.add(TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
         lp.add(TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
         lp.add(TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
         lp.add(TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
     }

     imp.imprimirBalcao(lp);
}
```

**Impresso.java**

```
public void imprimirBalcao(List lista) {
    Frame f = new Frame("Frame temporário");
    f.pack();
    Toolkit tk = f.getToolkit();
    PrintJob pj = tk.getPrintJob(f, "MP4200", null);

    if (pj != null) {
        Graphics g = pj.getGraphics();
        g.drawString("Relacao de produtos", 50, 30);
        int y = 70;
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            g.drawString("Código: " + lista.get(i), 50, y);
            y += 25;
            g.drawString("Nome: " + lista.get(i), 50, y);
            y += 25;
            g.drawString("Quantidade: " + lista.get(i), 50, y);
            y += 25;
            g.drawString("Preço: " + lista.get(i), 50, y);
            y += 50;
        }

        g.dispose();

        pj.end();
    }

    f.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Quais são os tipos do `TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 1)`, do `TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 2)`, do `TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 3)` e do `TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 6)`? Preciso dessa informação para elaborar a minha resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 1) tipo int, TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 2) tipo String, TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 3) tipo Double, TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 6) tipo Double.

Comment: É Double com letra maiúscula mesmo ou double com letra minúscula?

Comment: Aliás, o primeiro é Integer ao invés de int. Correto?

Comment: esta do jeito que passei a você acima. int e Double.

Comment: Não seria retornando uma `List<List<?>>`? Uma `JTable` pode ser imaginada como uma matriz, retornar uma lista única parece um pouco bagunçado. É uma lista mesmo que precisa retornar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, modele algumas classes que descrevam o que é que você vai imprimir e coloque nelas um método responsável por imprimí-las. Vejamos, uma **relatação de produtos impressa** tem vários **produtos impressos** e cada produto impresso tem código, nome, quantidade e preço. Portanto:

```java
public class ProdutoImpresso implements Drawable {
    private final String codigo;
    private final String nome;
    private final String quantidade;
    private final String preco;

    public ProdutoImpresso(String codigo, String nome, String quantidade, String preco) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
        this.preco = preco;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(int x, int y, Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Código: " + codigo, x, y);
        g.drawString("Nome: " + nome, x, y + 25);
        g.drawString("Quantidade: " + quantidade, x, y + 50);
        g.drawString("Preço: " + preco, x, y + 75);
    }
}
```

```java
public class RelacaoDeProdutos implements Drawable {
    private final List<ProdutoImpresso> itens;

    public RelacaoDeProdutos(List<ProdutoImpresso> itens) {
        this.itens = itens;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(int x, int y, Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Relação de produtos", x, y);
        int y2 = y + 40;
        for (ProdutoImpresso i : itens) {
            i.draw(x, y2, g);
            y2 += 125;
        }
    }
}
```

Aquela interface ali é porque você provavelmente vai querer estender isso para outras coisas que você pode querer imprimir:

```java
public interface Drawable {
    public void draw(int x, int y, Graphics g);
}
```

Tendo feito isso, as suas outras classes se tornam simples:

```java
public void capturaProduto() {    
    List<ProdutoImpresso> lp = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < TbProdutosVenda.getRowCount(); i++) {
        ProdutoImpresso item = new ProdutoImpresso(
                TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 1).toString(),
                TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 2).toString(),
                TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 3).toString(),
                TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
        lp.add(item);
    }

    RelacaoDeProdutos r = new RelacaoDeProdutos(lp);
    imp.imprimir("MP4200", 50, 30, r);
}
```

```java
public void imprimir(String titulo, int x, int y, Drawable toDraw) {
    Frame f = new Frame("Frame temporário");
    f.pack();
    Toolkit tk = f.getToolkit();
    PrintJob pj = tk.getPrintJob(f, titulo, null);
    Graphics g = null;
    try {
        if (pj != null) {
            g = pj.getGraphics();
            toDraw.draw(x, y, g);
        }
    } finally {
        if (g != null) g.dispose();
        if (pj != null) pj.end();
        f.dispose();
    }
}
```

O bloco `finally` serve para o caso de ele finalizar os objetos mesmo se você passar algum `Drawable` mal-comportado que lance uma exceção no método `draw`.

A vantagem de fazer desse jeito é que sempre que você tiver alguma coisa que pode ser desenhada na tela, na impressora ou em algum outro lugar, basta você implementar a interface `Drawable` e pronto. Além disso, sempre que você tiver um objeto complexo de ser impresso/desenhado no todo, vale usar a estratégia de que cada parte é responsável pelo seu próprio desenho, fazendo um `Drawable` ser composto de outros `Drawable`s.

Por fim, para imprimir qualquer `Drawable`, tudo que você precisará fazer é (depois de ter criado o `Drawable`):

```java
    imp.imprimir(titulo, x, y, drawable);
```

Se você estiver com o Java 8, pode tentar um passo mais ousado e fazer a sua `Drawable` assim:

```java
public interface Drawable {
    public void draw(int x, int y, Graphics g);

    public default void imprimir(String titulo, int x, int y) {
        Frame f = new Frame("Frame temporário");
        f.pack();
        Toolkit tk = f.getToolkit();
        PrintJob pj = tk.getPrintJob(f, titulo, null);
        Graphics g = null;
        try {
            if (pj != null) {
                g = pj.getGraphics();
                draw(x, y, g);
            }
        } finally {
            if (g != null) g.dispose();
            if (pj != null) pj.end();
            f.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

E com isso o seu método `capturaProduto()` fica assim:

```java
public void capturaProduto() {    
    List<ProdutoImpresso> lp = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < TbProdutosVenda.getRowCount(); i++) {
        ProdutoImpresso item = new ProdutoImpresso(
                TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 1).toString(),
                TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 2).toString(),
                TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 3).toString(),
                TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
        lp.add(item);
    }

    RelacaoDeProdutos r = new RelacaoDeProdutos(lp);
    r.imprimir("MP4200", 50, 30);
}
```

E então você não precisa mais usar o objeto `imp` da classe `Impresso`.

Comment: public class RelacaoDeProdutos implements Drawable {
    private final List<ProdutoImpresso> itens;

    public RelacaoDeProdutos(List<ProdutoImpresso> itens) {
        this.itens = item;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(int x, int y, Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Relação de produtos", x, y);
        int y2 = y + 40;
        for (ItemImpressao i : itens) {
            i.draw(x, y2, g);
            y2 += 125;
        }
    }
} 

No trecho você se refere ao  this.itens = item; mas item vem de onde. E no trecho ItemImpressao i : itens ItemImpressao se refere ao que?

Comment: @ClaytonQuintiliano Corrigido. É porque quando eu fiz isso, eu mudei o nome de classes e de variáveis várias vezes e esses dois tinham ficado para trás.

Comment: obtive uma Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.
Na conversão deste objeto    (Integer) TbProdutosVenda.getValueAt(i, 1)

Comment: @ClaytonQuintiliano Foi no `getValueAt(i, 1)`? Se sim, é porque ele não era `int`, e sim `String` mesmo.

Comment: Sim foi neste item mesmo, você diz que ele é String no modelo do JTable? Se for ai ali esta todos como objetos.

Comment: @ClaytonQuintiliano Editado de novo. Aparentemente ele sempre está vindo como `String` no `JTable`. Mas forçando com o `toString()` como você fazia, desde que não venha `null`, ele resolve para qualquer tipo, ao menos para os tipos simples que você está usando até agora, sendo ou não `String`.